# Changing value of static variable outside of a function

Tags: c, pointers, reference, static

I am tasked with trying to change the value of a static variable outside of a function in C.

I have viewed some posts on this topic, particularly some comments from this post: 
[How to change local static variable value from outside function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117372/how-to-change-local-static-variable-value-from-outside-function)
There is a comment that says to pass the variable through a reference/pointer parameter or to return by reference, but I feel as though I am lacking the understanding to implement this.

My understanding of a static variable is that memory for the variable is allocated only once, and is not released when the variable goes out of scope. According to [What does "static" mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-c), the static variable in a function retains its value between invocations, and is seen only in the file that it is declared in. I set up a basic example to show how static variables are traditionally used:

```
int myFunction();

    void main() {

    printf("%d ", myFunction());
    // console should show value of 1
    printf("%d ", myFunction());
    // console should show value of 2
    printf("%d ", myFunction());
    // console should show value of 3

    return 0;
}

int myFunction() {
    static int counter = 0;
    counter++;
    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the function return the address of the variable.

```
int* myFunction() {
    static int counter = 0; 
    counter++; 
    return &counter; 
}
```

Then, in `main` you can use this function like:

```
int* ptr = myFunction();
*ptr = 0; // reset counter back to zero
```